# I have to use "../" in dreamweaver on some links. Is this normal?

Tags: hyperlink, dreamweaver

I cannot find anything on the internet probably because I'm not sure how to ask the question properly, but I cannot seem to figure out why on some images or links to pages i have to put ../ in front of the file name for dreamWeaver to see the file. It's not every file just some of them.

Comment: body {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px 0px #000, -1px 0px 3px 0px #000;
  background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.3.1.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if the pages or images are in a separate folder.

If your page is in root/pages/home/index.html and your image is in root/pages/home/images/image.jpg then you will only need `images/image.jpg` but if the image is in root/pages/about/images/image.jpg then you require .. because it's outside of the local folder.

This is a good link: https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: It seems that by having my templates in the /templates folder as suggested by adobe, I am having to put the "../" on everything basically. It seems like there is something out of the normal here.

Comment: Best thing to do in my opinion @KevinOuellette is to keep your html files and image folder within the same parent folder, this will prevent it, alternatively, within dreamweaver you can insert a link and select which page/file you would like it to link to!